# Surround numbers with double quotes with SED

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a simple requirement, I have input likeL

```
4,23139,,"XYZ"
```

in a text file and I need output like

```
"4","23139","","ARCMsgEnum".
```

The command I have written works fine in some cases:

```
sed 's/[0-9]*[0-9]/"&"/g' inputTestData.txt | sed s/,,/,\"\",/g
```

but there are some lines which have input as timestamp:

```
4,23139,,"XYZ","2008-09-04 08:11:33.51 AM"
```

So the desired output is:

```
"4","23139","","XYZ","2008-09-04 08:11:33.51 AM"
```

but the above command gives me output like:

```
"4","23139","","XYZ",""2008"-"09"-"04" "08":"11":"33"."46" AM"
```

Comment: I have asked a similirar  question but somehow I am unable to get this by myself. 
Input:
1234.34,a,Baghdad,+345.65,+,++ +5335.643,cat,dog,,+,++,+644.65,a,b

Desired output:
1234.34,a,Baghdad,345.65,+,++
5335.643,cat,dog,,+,++,644.65,a,b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' inputfile
```

This would strip the quotes first and then insert quotes within parts within commas.

As an example:

```
$ echo 4,23139,,\"XYZ\",\"2008-09-04 08:11:33.51 AM\" | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/[^,]*/"&"/g'
"4","23139","","XYZ","2008-09-04 08:11:33.51 AM"
```

Comment: Very nice +1, good thinking to strip first, I just brute forced it :/

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't think of a clever robust way, you could use:

```
$ sed -re 's/^[^"]/"&/' 
       -e 's/[^"]$/&"/' 
       -e 's/,,/,"",/g' 
       -e 's/([^"]),/\1",/g' 
       -e 's/,([^"])/,"\1/g' file
```

Comment: +1.  The brute approach would work with all sort of crazy inputs like `foo,bar"baz,foobar`.

Comment: I have asked a similirar  question but somehow I am unable to get this by myself. 
Input:
1234.34,a,Baghdad,+345.65,+,++ +5335.643,cat,dog,,+,++,+644.65,a,b

Desired output:
1234.34,a,Baghdad,345.65,+,++
5335.643,cat,dog,,+,++,644.65,a,b

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
sed -re 's/([0-9]+),/"\1",/g' -e 's/,,/,"",/g' inputTestData.txt
```

You were pretty close. Just needed to check for numbers that are followed by `,`

For example:

```
$ cat inputTestData.txt
4,23139,,"XYZ","2008-09-04 08:11:33.51 AM"

$ sed -re 's/([0-9]+),/"\1",/g' -e 's/,,/,"",/g' inputTestData.txt
"4","23139","","XYZ","2008-09-04 08:11:33.51 AM"
```

**Note**

You don't need to pipe one `sed` output to another `sed` for multiple regex. You can use `-e` option followed by `s/../../g` multiple times

Comment: `([0-9]*[0-9])` could just be `([0-9]+)`.

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks for pointing it out. actually I was trying with `[0-9]*` initially but gave some false results so just appended `[0-9]`. Will edit.

Comment: `*` is zero or more while `+` is one or more so `[0-9]*[0-9]` is zero or more digits followed by 1 digit which is just one or more digit.

Comment: @sudo_O agree with you and knew it. I was somehow trying to cover `,,` case in a single regex. `[0-9]*` worked for it but converted `"XYZ"` to `"XYZ"""` so ended up appending `[0-9]` instead of replacing `*` with `+`, my bad.